# C# Hooking specific Keyboard keystroke and stop system propagation

Tags: c#, hook

I have an application where I have multiple keyboards connected through USB.

I need to hook a **specific** keyboard to get the keypress directly into the software, even if this one is not on the foreground. This so far works based on [this project](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17123/Using-Raw-Input-from-C-to-handle-multiple-keyboard). The other keyboards shall work as normal.

Although it seems by using Direct Input, it is not possible to stop propagation (we don't want other apps to get that particular keyboard input).

Concerning Global Hook, it can block the keypress system-wise, but it is impossible, as far as I know, to identify the source of the keystroke (which keyboard it is from) and thus to selectively block them.

There is another project, [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/716591/Combining-Raw-Input-and-keyboard-Hook-to-selective), that combines the two, but it is quite messy and heavy.

Is there a better way to achieve this? I am surprised that simple task is so complex.

Comment: Do you want to make that software for only windows or you want to make it cross-platform?

Comment: I don't know if this is still possible, but in the 90s, I used LibUSB (a C++ library) to directly communicate with any USB device.  I wonder if you could use this to 'grab' the keyboard and prevent Windows as seeing this as a keyboard, and then you post WM_CHAR messages directly to the window/application you wish to control?

Comment: @Neil As far as I know not because given it goes into keyboard class, it is directly handled by the system.

Comment: I believe LibUSB intercepted devices /before/ Windows decides it's a keyboard.  Basically, the keyboard is 'no longer a keyboard', it's a basic USB/HID device that you manually control.

Answer (score -1):

If you are going to make the app windows only, you should look into [Windows raw input api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/raw-input)

It isn't that complicated.

Comment: It's basically step #1, the problem is that Raw Input cannot stop propagation.

Comment: @Damien you want to deny other apps access to that keyboard?

Comment: Not specifically, just stop the keystrokes from specific keyboard being propagated.

Comment: @Damien so for example you want to disable key H from keyboard B, but only so that when key H is pressed on that keyboard only your app gets the keystroke and nothing else?

Comment: @Damien perhaps this link might help you https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14485/Low-level-Windows-API-hooks-from-C-to-stop-unwante